# Add Job Title in Order Confirmation Email Magento 2

Tags: magento2, php, magento2.3.4

I am trying to find way to show the Customer **"Job Title"** into order confirmation email.

[image]

Comment: Have you considered adding it to the address templates?

Comment: Can you explain more please what you mean by this ?